# guzzle не отправляются асинхронные запросы

Tags: php, guzzle

Не отправляется асинхронный запрос. 
Синхронные отправляются.

```
require 'guzzle/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

// Синхронный запрос
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://site.ru');
echo $res->getBody();
// Синхронный запрос работает, все окей

// Асинхронный запрос
$client     = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request    = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://site.ru');
$promise    = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo $response->getBody();
});
// Асинхронный запрос не отправляется, если не вызвать метод wait() у объекта $promise.
// Но если вызвать wait() - то это уже будет не асинхронность, а ждать будем ответа и потом только будет второй запрос
// Если вызвать метод wait у объекта $promise, тогда этот запрос будет ожидать ответа, никакой асинхронности
$promise->wait();
```

**На сайте куда ведёт запрос, я сделал логирование в файл при запросах.**

Когда отправляю синхронный запрос ИЛИ вызываю **$promise->wait()** метод - тогда в файл логируется.

Если я не вызываю **$promise->wait()**; - не записывается лог, соответственно запроса нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
$promise->wait();
```

Это ожидание того, что всё идет асинхронно. 
Ожидаем, когда все потоки завершат свою работу.